# Why does the GroupNames.org table of transitive groups omit $S_6$ and $S_7$?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Obviously $S_n$s are all transitive. But GroupNames.org's ["Transitive groups of degree up to 31"](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/T31.html) table seems not to include $S_6$, $S_7$. Tell me why.

(And I also don't figure out reason why $C_{23}\rtimes C_{22}$ is not in the table..?)

Sorry if I make elementary mistakes.

Comment: The tables seem to be very incomplete. For example, there are $50$ transitive groups of degree $8$ but only $43$ are listed.

Comment: If you want to know the "why" of something, it's usually best to ask the source. The site's [About page](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/about.html) has a link to contact information for questions and comments.